# Crop UIImage in oval shape

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

How to crop UIImage on oval shape?

Answer (score 0):

The HeadsUP GUI example in the SDK shows you how to add rounded corners to a UIView you would be able to modify that code to do what you need.